# Как убрать # (хэш/решетку) в URL при прокрутке к якорю

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый вечер. Такой вопрос, как убрать # (хэш/решетку) в URL при прокрутке к якорю по данному примеру:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);

    $("a[href^=#]").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        $(document).off("scroll");
        $(menu_selector + " a.active").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");
        var hash = $(this).attr("href");
        var target = $(hash);

        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 900, function(){
            window.location.hash = hash;
            $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
        });

    });

});
```

Comment: Не надо убирать.

Comment: почему не надо?

Comment: Потому что url с решёткой можно сохранить в закладки, либо переслать другому человеку - в таком случае будет открываться сразу нужная секция.

Comment: Чем Вам мешает решетка ?

Comment: это лендинг, тут если прокрутить немного ничего страшного, а когда стоит хэш, смотрится как "прошлый век"

Answer (score 3):

Я хочу присоединиться к комментаторам и поддержать мнение, что не нужно убирать "якорь". Он позволяет получить ссылку на конкретный участок страницы и совершенно не выглядит как "прошлый век", что за странные предрассудки.

К тому же, странно и нелогично использовать технологию (прямо по назначению) и избавляться от половины ее "назначения". Почему бы просто не прокрутить страницу с помощью javascript при клике на элемент? И никакого хеша не будет.

Так или иначе, вопрос требует ответа. Это ваше дело как использовать доступные инструменты.

Убрать якорь без перезагрузки страницы можно, насколько я знаю, только с помощью History API, к примеру, таким кодом:

```
if(window.history && history.pushState)
    history.pushState({foo: 'bar'}, 'Title', location.href.replace(location.hash,''));
```

Проверка необходима, так как старые браузеры не поддерживают этот функционал. Хотя, к счастью, на данный момент абсолютное большинство пользователей пользуются совместимыми браузерами.

Comment: Проверка `window.history` лишняя, поскольку `history.back()` - очень старая штука, так что объект `history` точно будет. Достаточно проверить `history.pushState`.